# changing url 301 redirection with htaccess or php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect, http-status-code-301

`example.com/a=process&b=5&b_id=5`

how can I redirect this to

```
example.com/a=process&b_id=5
```

So I can delete b=5 for all incoming url. But "a" , "b" and "b_id" changable not static. How can I do this?

Comment: You want to redirect to another domain? what is the condition of redirection- value of b and b_id should be same?

Comment: No not another domain. I want to delete a query variable with htaccess  there are different variables in url but I want to delete b variable only

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you don't want to use b, simply don't use b in your script.

Comment: .htaccess will work on server side, and the url will remain unchanged for the browser. So I think you really need to explain a lot more things, where does theses url came from, when do you want the rewrite to occurs, why are you talking of redirections, etc.

Comment: URL came from google indexs. I want it for google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do internal redirection, use the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# The query variable b is comming first.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^b=[0-9]*&(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %2?%1 [L,NS]

# The query variable b is comming in middle.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&b=[0-9]*&(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %3?%1&%2 [L,NS]

# The query variable b is comming last.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&b=[0-9]*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %2?%1 [L,NS]
```

Then just print the `print_r($_GET);` The query variable `b` won't be in the array.

If you want to do external redirection, use the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# The query variable b is comming first.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^b=[0-9]*&(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1 [R,L,NS]

# The query variable b is comming in middle.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&b=[0-9]*&(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1&%2 [R,L,NS]

# The query variable b is comming last.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&b=[0-9]*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1 [R,L,NS]
```

Have a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html to know about the R, L, NS, etc.

Comment: thank you very much.I do not know where b comes.Do I must write all code above?I want it for google. because google indexed my site links but I don't want b variable because don't use it no more.